How to train a DL model in Python when samples are 2d number arrays with different length?
I want to create a deep learning model, I know how to do so with simple samples where each row of dataset represents a sample, but my samples are 2D table of numbers. The features are the same in all samples but their length (rows) varies from sample to sample, like tables below.
Sample1:



Feature 1
Feature 2
...
Feature n
Result




row 1F1
row 1F2
...
row 1Fn
S1


row 2F1
row 2F2
...
row 2Fn
S1


...
...
...
...



row 1000F1
row 1000F2
...
row 1000Fn
S1



Sample2:



Feature 1
Feature 2
...
Feature n
Result




row 1F1
row 1F2
...
row 1Fn
S2


row 2F1
row 2F2
...
row 2Fn
S2


...
...
...
...



row 1200F1
row 1200F2
...
row 1200Fn
S2



Feature are the same, for example let's say feature 1 represents "Name" in all samples, feature 2 represents "city" and so on; but the number of rows in each sample varies.
I can not put away some rows to make the samples equal in length since they affect result. I also can not turn rows into new features to transform samples into 1D array of numbers because there are too many rows to do that.

I want to know do I need to somehow normalize the dimension of the samples? (if yes how can I do that?)
or Is there a deep learning model that can take inputs with different dimensions like my samples?

(I am using Python; I read that one way is to encode and decode the samples using LSTM seq-2-seq but I don't know if it is the right way to handle my dataset.)
Thanks in advance.


Is there a deep learning model that can take inputs with different dimensions like my samples?

This data format is suitable for a 1D convolutional net. Convolutional nets are able to process sequences that are long and irregular, both of which apply in this case.

I read that one way is to encode and decode the samples using LSTM

I think that sequence lengths beyond a couple hundred steps are considered too long for LSTMs, so LSTMs can't be used directly here. But if you first use a convolutional net to compress things down, you could follow it up with an LSTM at that stage.

Suggestion in response to details about the dataset provided in the comments (binary classification task; data set size ~100; 7 features; irregular sequence lengths of 6k-7k).
I think my first attempt would be along the lines of:

Stacking dilated convolutions at the input in order to have the layers 'pull in' information from a wide receptive field
Maxpooling and regular convolutions for compressing the sequence length and generating new features
A final out classification layer (dense, returning logits)

I'd train with a batch size of 1 since the dataset is small and the sequences are irregular. We'd need to consider whether the dataset is balanced or not, and potentially also synthesise samples. Sample synthesis could be just for the minority class, or for the dataset as a whole as an augmentation technique, if not both.
See this answer for similarly-architected sequential convnet I recently coded up.

So I can give samples with different length to CNN and pooling and padding in CNN will take care of the irregularity of the data, am I right?

Yes, pooling layers can be used to handle the irregularity but the net won't automatically figure out the appropriate pooling - you'd need to specify what type of pooling and where it goes. Padding is also something you can specify, especially if you want certain operations to preserve the sequence length. I don't think padding is an important consideration for this case. I can be more specific if you elaborate on the data dimensions (e.g. roughly how many samples, the feature size, etc).

I apologize for responding late. I roughly have 100 samples. Each sample has 7 feature columns and 1 result column which makes a total of 8 columns for each sample (features' title are the same in all samples of course). The length of the samples (their number of rows) varies from 5000 to 6000. All the features are float numbers while the result column is binary Yes/No for each row.

I think my first attempt would be along the lines of: stacking dilated convolutions at the input in order to have the layers 'pull in' information from a wide receptive field; followed by maxpooling & regular conv for compressing the sequence length & generating new features. I'd train with batch_size=1 since the dataset is small & the sequences are irregular. See this answer for similarly-architected convnet I recently coded up. I've updated my answer with more details. Happy to have a go with your data if you could upload or email it.

Thank you so much for your guidance, it's been a great help. I will try to apply it and ask for more help if needed. Thanks again.
